# Get specific string

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to get a specific string from a bigger string:

From these `Abcd1234_Tot9012_tore.dr` or `Abcd1234_Tot9012.tore.dr`

I want to get those numbers which are between `Tot` and `_` or `.` , so I should get `9012`. Important thing is that the number of characters before and after these numbers may vary.

Could anyone give me a nice solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should also work if you are looking only for numbers after Tot

```
[srikanth@myhost ~]$ echo "Abcd1234_Tot9012_tore.dr" | awk ' { match($0,/Tot([0-9]*)/,a); print a[1]; } '
9012
[srikanth@myhost ~]$ echo "Abcd1234_Tot9012.tore.dr" | awk ' { match($0,/Tot([0-9]*)/,a); print a[1]; } '
9012
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is tagged as bash/sed but perl is clearer for this kind of task, in my opinion. In case you're interested:

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /Tot([0-9]+)[._]/' input.txt
```

`-ne` tells perl to loop the specified one-liner over the input file without printing anything by default.

The regex is readable as: match Tot, followed by a number, followed by either a dot or an underscore; capture the number (that's what the parens are for). As it's the first/capture group it's assigned to the `$1` variable, which then is printed.

Comment: Yep, but your oneliner is wrong, it will only print a number after `Tot`. I'd write this as `perl -ne 'print "$1\n" foreach m/(\d+)[._]/g'`

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the OP? I take it that's exactly what they want - to capture the number between `Tot` and either `_` or `.`. The OP wants to get 9012 but not 1234, for example.

Comment: Oops, yes, it was me who misunderstood the OP :p Your solution is therefore correct.

Comment: @downvoter: why the downvote? Leave a comment if you think this solution is inappropiate so I can improve it. I think perl can be relevant as the OP wasn't specific about the tools, and perl in this mode can actually be faster than sed sometimes.

Comment: Perl's strict 'awk' emulation mode is `perl -a` (which autosplits the input lines into an array `@F`), and has to be combined with `-p` or `-n`).  The `-n` is derived from `sed`; it suppresses the automatic print.  Formally, `-p` is not directly from either 'awk' or 'sed', I think.

Comment: @Jonathan: good insight, I didn't know that. I'll remove the comment as it's probably confusing and doesn't contribute much.

Comment: Probably the simplest solution.  Strictly, the second `+` in your regex could be omitted, but the output will be the same whether it is present or not (and will be correct).

Comment: @Jonathan: you're right, thanks. I removed it, as it may be confusing for someone trying to read/understand the regex even if it's not wrong per se.

Answer (score 4):

Pure Bash:

```
string="Abcd1234_Tot9012_tore.dr"        # or ".tore.dr"

string=${string##*_Tot}
string=${string%%[_.]*}

echo "$string"
```

Remove longest leading part ending with '_Tot'.

Remove longest trailing part beginning with '_' or '.'.

Result:

```
9012
```

Comment: Nice one! Albeit a little criptic, for me at least.

Comment: this needs to be ${string##...} or it will fail on the input "_Tot_Tot9012..."

Comment: +1, but why extglob and @([_.])* instead of simply ${string%%[._]*} ?

Answer (score 1):

#### awk

```
string="Abcd1234_Tot9012_tore.dr"
num=$(awk -F'Tot|[._]' '{print $3}' <<<"$string")
```

#### sed

```
string="Abcd1234_Tot9012_tore.dr"
num=$(sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{4\}\).*$/\1/' <<<"$string")
```

#### Example

```
$ string="Abcd1234_Tot9012_tore.dr"; awk -F'Tot|[._]' '{print $3}' <<<"$string"
9012

$ string="Abcd1234_Tot9013.tore.dr"; sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{4\}\).*$/\1/' <<<"$string"
9013
```

Comment: Both of these are wayy too input dependent, the perl solution really is the cleanest of all here

Comment: @fge please explain how `/Tot([0-9]+)[._]+/'` is less input dependent than `/.*\([0-9]\{4\}\).*$/`

Comment: Because it will match even if there is no `Tot` in the string at all. What's more, the OP never said it had to be four digits only. And, and, and.

Comment: @fge so you're telling me that because I *don't* match on `Tot` that I am *too* input dependent?

Comment: @user1116360 wrt fge's comment, change the `\{4\}` to a `\+` if you decide to use my `sed` version, although I would go with `awk` as I think its more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `perl` one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/.*(?<=Tot)([0-9]{4}).*/\1/' file
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
Abcd1234_Tot9012_tore.dr
Abcd1234_Tot9012.tore.dr

[jaypal:~/Temp] perl -pe 's/.*(?<=Tot)([0-9]{4}).*/\1/' file
9012
9012
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` you can do:

```
str=Abcd1234_Tot9012.tore.dr; grep -o "Tot[0-9]*" <<< $str|grep -o "[0-9]*$"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
9012
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "Abcd1234_Tot9012_tore.dr\nAbcd1234_Tot9012.tore.dr" | 
sed 's/Tot[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[_.].*/\n\1/;s/.*\n//'
9012
9012
```

This works equally as well:

```
echo -e "Abcd1234_Tot9012_tore.dr\nAbcd1234_Tot9012.tore.dr" |
sed 's/.*Tot\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
9012
9012
```