# bash: Find irregular values in strings

Tags: string, bash

I'm looking to fetch a value *after* a match in a string.
Lets say I have two string:

```
string1="Name: John Doe Age: 28 City: Oklahoma City"
string2="Name: Jane Age: 29 Years City: Boston"
```

Now I want to set three parameters: Name, Age and City.
If I were to do:

```
name=$(echo "$string1" | awk '{ print $2 $3 }')
city=$(echo "$string1" | awk '{ print $5 }')
city=$(echo "$string1" | awk '{ print $8 $9 }
```

It would work for string1, but obviously not for string2.
After some googling I believe I should put it in some kind of array, but I do not really know how to proceed.

Basically, I want everything after *Name:* and before *Age:* to be parameter **$name**. Everything between *Age:* and *City:* to be **$age**, and so on.

Best regards

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needs bash version 3 or higher:

```
if [[ $string1 =~ ^Name:\ (.*)\ Age:\ (.*)\ City:\ (.*) ]] ; then
    name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    age=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    city=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
fi
```

You might need `Age:\ ([0-9]*).*\ City:` if you do not want "Years" to be included in `$years`.

Comment: Nice but it will return age="29 Years" instead of age="29"

Comment: @choroba you should revert the change, that is expected behavior according to the OP.

Comment: @choroba: Awesome. Works just as I expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution (taken partly from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704038/get-specific-string/8704178#870417)):

Capture name:

```
name=`perl -ne 'print $1 if /Name: ([a-zA-Z ]+) Age:/' <<< $string`
```

Capture age:

```
age=`perl -ne 'print $1 if /Age: ([0-9a-zA-Z ]+) City:/' <<< $string`
```

-ne tells perl to loop the specified one-liner over the input file or standard input without printing anything by default (you could call it awk emulation mode).

The parens in the regexes specify the bits you're interested in capturing. The other fragments acts as delimiters.

After running both of these through `$string1` of your example I get 'John Doe' and '28'.

Edit: replaced `echo $string` with `<<< $string`, which is nice.

Comment: Same problem, it will also return age="29 Years" instead of age="29"

Comment: See the other comments, I also think that's right according to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is the best solution for this because you can set the field separator to a regex and then your fields are $2, $3 and $4

```
name=$(awk -F'[[:alpha:]]+: ' '{print $2}' <<<"$string1")
 age=$(awk -F'[[:alpha:]]+: ' '{print $3}' <<<"$string1")
city=$(awk -F'[[:alpha:]]+: ' '{print $4}' <<<"$string1")
```

Comment: Nice but it will return `age="29 Years"` instead of `age="29"`

Comment: @anubhava according to the OP, that is correct behavior. *"Everything between Age: and City: to be $age"*

Answer (score 0):

Consider these commands:

```
name=$(awk -F": |Age" '{print $2}' <<< $string1)
age=$(awk -F": |City|Years" '{print $3}' <<< $string1)
city=$(awk -F"City: " '{print $2}' <<< $string1)
```

Comment: This will return age="29" instead of age="29 Years" ;P

Comment: That's intentional, age="29 years" in one case and age="28" in another doesn't make a lot of sense. You can't do any comparison with `$age` variable then.

Comment: It may be intentional, but it's not correct according to the specification given. Nowhere does he say he wants to do a numeric comparison on $age.  He, however, did say *Everything between Age: and City: to be $age*

Comment: I would leave it to OP to pick & choose the best behavior. If I am coding it I would never grab `" years"` in my `$age` variable. If at all I need to print `"29 years"` I will append it myself later.

Comment: @anubhava: Thank you for your effort. I appreciate it. I actually intended to keep it all, but again. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
string1="Name: John Doe Age: 28 City: Oklahoma City"
string1ByRow=$(echo "$string1" | perl -pe 's/(\w+:)/\n$1\n/g' | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/^ *//')
string1Keys=$(echo "$string1ByRow" | grep ':$' | sed 's/:$//')
string1Vals=$(echo "$string1ByRow" | grep -v ':$')

echo "$string1Keys"
Name
Age
City

echo "$string1Vals"
John Doe 
28 
Oklahoma City
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use three `perl` one-liners for assigning value to your variables -

```
name=$(perl -pe 's/.*(?<=Name: )([A-Za-z ]+)(?=Age).*/\1/' file)

age=$(perl -pe 's/.*(?<=Age: )([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)(?=City).*/\1/' file)
```

**`OR`**

```
age=$(perl -pe 's/.*(?<=Age: )([0-9 ]+)(?=Years|City).*/\1/' file)

city=$(perl -pe 's/.*(?<=City: )([A-Za-z ]+)"/\1/' file)
```

**Test File:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
string1="Name: John Doe Age: 28 City: Oklahoma City"
string2="Name: Jane Age: 29 Years City: Boston"
```

**Name:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] perl -pe 's/.*(?<=Name: )([A-Za-z ]+)(?=Age).*/\1/' file
John Doe 
Jane
```

**Age:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] perl -pe 's/.*(?<=Age: )([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)(?=City).*/\1/' file
28 
29 Years
```

**OR**
    if you just want the `age` and `not years` then

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] perl -pe 's/.*(?<=Age: )([0-9 ]+)(?=Years|City).*/\1/' file
28 
29
```

**City:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] perl -pe 's/.*(?<=City: )([A-Za-z ]+)"/\1/' file
Oklahoma City
Boston
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a generic solution:

```
keys=() values=()
for word in $string; do
    wlen=${#word}
    if [[ ${word:wlen-1:wlen} = : ]]; then
        keys+=("${word:0:wlen-1}") values+=("")
    else
        alen=${#values[@]}
        values[alen-1]=${values[alen-1]:+${values[alen-1]} }$word
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

bash-3.2$ cat sample.log

```
string1="Name: John Doe Age: 28 City: Oklahoma City"
string2="Name: Jane Age: 29 Years City: Boston"
```

Using awk **match** inbuilt function:

```
awk ' { match($0,/Name:([A-Za-z ]*)Age:/,a); match($0,/Age:([ 0-9]*)/,b);  match($0,/City:([A-Za-z ]*)/,c); print a[1]":" b[1]":"c[1] } ' sample.log
```

Output:

```
 John Doe : 28 : Oklahoma City
 Jane : 29 : Boston
```

Comment: You can also use awk inbuilt **FS** parameter and do this way as well.

`bash-3.2$ awk  'BEGIN {FS="Name:|Age:|Years|Years.*City:|City:"; } { if(NF >=4) { name=$2; age=$3; city=$4; print name":"age":"city; } }' sample.log` 
**Output**
` John Doe : 28 : Oklahoma City"
 Jane : 29 : Boston"`